# How to use SQLiteOpenHelper in recyclerView?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to use SQLite in recyclerView's onBindViewHolder. Normal Activity can declare openHelper like

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

and DatabaseHelper class extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

But how to declare at `onBindViewHolder` in recyclerView class? This is my code.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(homeAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.homeAuth.setText(authList.get(position));
        holder.homeName.setText(nameList.get(position));
        holder.homeIntro.setText(introList.get(position));
        holder.homePk.setText(pkList.get(position));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Context context = v.getContext();
                final String serverURL = "http://youngh.cafe24app.com/qrock/views/qrock_pk/user_email";

                myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);  //is it Possible?
                final String token = myDb.getToken();
                final String email = myDb.getEmail();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, mainActivity.class);   
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                ((Activity) context).finish();

                ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.xml.madefadein, R.xml.splashfadeout);
            }
        });
    }
```

I declare database class generally. Is it possible to declare SQLiteOpenHelper class in the normal class?

Comment: You are lacking some basic programming and oop concepts man...

Comment: instead of creating a new object on `onBindViewHolder`  create `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);` inside RecyclerView's Adapter constructor

Comment: @Vucko Sorry.. I started android studio and OOP not long... I know constructer's parameter. but I didn't know how to convert to what constructer's parameter need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this

```
DatabaseHelper myDb;
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);
```

in RecyclerView's Adapter constructor and you can use it in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: But it return Context in can't be applied to adapter.

Comment: pass context to constructor and replace `new DatabaseHelper(this)` with `new DatabaseHelper(context)`

Answer (score 2):

If you call `this` inside the `setOnClickListener` it will refer the `onclickListener` object not `context`. You can use  `myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context);` inside your onClickListener.

But, The best way of implementation is initializing DatabaseHelper in **adapter constructor**.

In your adapter constructor get `Context` as a parameter and initialize your DatabaseHelper there.

Your implementation should be like this:

```
class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>{
   private DatabaseHelper myDb;

   public YourAdapter(Context context){
      myDb = new DatabaseHelper(context)
   }
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: You wrote this almoust 3 years ago but you have no idea how help me today :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

check what `DatabaseHelper` need as constructor's parameter. I assume it's `Context`, so `new DatabaseHelper(context);` should work